# Dropping event due to window no focus

Tags: android, warnings

I am getting this `warning` but not able to catch reason ?

```
Dropping event due to no window focus: 
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0,
flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1057872, downTime=1057872, deviceId=4,
displayId=0, source=0x101 }
```

Can anybody explain, What's the reason for this Warning?

Comment: One way this can happen is if the user types on a hardware keyboard during an activity transition.

Comment: on the emulator click on `recent apps button` then `back again to your app`

Comment: Thanks Basheer, I was going crazy over this thinking it was my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly normal if you take any action in response to this event that causes your window to lose focus. It's not a problem.

Note however that it is generally good policy to respond to ACTION_UP for KEYCODE_BACK, not ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: This is a problem in Android TV apps where D-Pad is used and no touch screen available. What do we do to get the focus in the window?

Comment: @user846316 you can't take window focus back once you have given it up. if you have a specific scenario in which you think you need to give window focus to something you don't control, and then somehow get window focus back, open a question on your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the `android:windowIsTranslucent`,then it works:

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!--<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. What worked for me was to go to the emulator and press the `off` key. Basically, you turn the screen back on as if it was on your wrist.